# Hibernate criteria for non-mapped property

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria-api

I have a tree-like object, managed by Hibernate. The object has a list of children and each child has its own `custom_order` within a parent:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="MyClass" .../>
  <property .../>
  <property .../>
  <list name="children" cascade="save-update" inverse="false">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <index column="custom_order"/>
    <one-to-many class="MyClass"/>
  </list>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The `custom_order` exists here in order to maintain the order of children within a parent but has no representation in the Java POJO and is managed directly by Hibernate. The only thing I have to do is to supply a list and `custom_order` will be auto-generated. So far so good.

What I want to achieve is the ability to use Criteria API and order by `custom_order`. At the moment I simply can not do anything like

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("custom_order"));
```

because there is no such POJO property.

Question: is there a way to use Criteria API for this scenario without adding POJO getter/setter?

EDIT: I don't mind adding relevant `custom_order` attribute to `MyClass` but I just don't think this is possible in Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to map `custom_order` attribute to `MyClass` without adding getter or setter for this attribute . Just configure `custom_order` attribute to be access by field .

Also , to prevent developers from changing the `custom_order` property using reflection , make `custom_order` to be read-only by setting `insert` and `update` to `false`:

```
<property name="customerOrder" column="custom_order" access="field" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

Currently , `Order` in Criteria API only can process mapped properties . If you don't want to map  `custom_order` attribute to `MyClass`, you can achieve your purpose if `Order` in Criteria API support sorting by native SQL. There are some requests for this support ([HHH-1356](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1356) ,[HHH-2381](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2381) , [HHH-3315)](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3315) but they are still unresolved now.

Luckily , someone had already [extended the Order class in order to support ordering by native SQL](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2381?focusedCommentId=27945&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-27945) . So ,if you don't map `custom_order` column for `MyClass` , you can simply use this extended Order class :

```
addOrder(new NativeSQLOrder("custom_order" ,true))
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot include unmapped property in criteria query. Hibernate will throw nu-mapped property exception when you do criteria.list() or criteria.uniqueResult().

Comment: Do you mind explaining how could I define a property for such a list index?

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties at runtime to your hibernate mapping and then use it in `Criteria`. [There's good article on infoq on how to add add custom fields dynamically.](http://www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields)